# Dart / Flutter: building widget from data obtained using async method

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to use a LietView.build populated by Widgets that obtain the data from an async method, before the widget is built. Here is my function that collects the data from a website:

```
fetchBasicData(String URL) async {
  final response = await http.get(URL);
  var document = parse(response.body);

  var result = new List<dom.Node>();
  result = document.getElementsByClassName('datas-nev');
  var dogName = result[0].nodes[1].toString();
  result = document.getElementsByClassName('datas-tipus');
  var dogBreed = result[0].nodes[1].toString();
  result = document.getElementsByClassName('datas-nem');
  var dogGender = result[0].nodes[1].toString();
  result = document.getElementsByClassName('datas-szin');
  var dogColor = result[0].nodes[1].toString();
  result = document.getElementsByClassName('datas-kor');
  var dogAge = result[0].nodes[1].toString();

  result = document.getElementsByClassName('pirobox_gall');
  String imageLink;
  imageLink = urlPrefix + result[0].nodes[0].attributes.values.first;

  return new Dog.basic(
      URL,
      dogName,
      dogBreed,
      dogGender,
      dogColor,
      dogAge,
      imageLink);
}
```

The function is executed and gathers the data, but the widget building fails with  `type '_Future' is not a subtype of type 'Widget' of 'child' where`

Here is the function that is supposed to build the widget:

```
buildBasicWidget(String URL) async {
    Dog myDog = await fetchBasicData(URL);
    return new SizedBox(
      width: 500.0,
      height: 400.0,
      child: new Card(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            //Header image row
            new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                    child: new FutureBuilder(
                        future: fetchPortrait(myDog.imageLink),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return new Image.network(
                              snapshot.data,
                              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                            );
                          } else {
                            if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              return new Text('Hiba');
                            }
                          }
                          return new Center(
                            child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        }))
              ],
            ), //Header image row
            new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                    child: new Text(
                  dogName,
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      color: Colors.black),
                ))
              ],
            ),
            new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                    child: new Text(myDog.dogColor +
                        'színű, ' +
                        myDog.dogBreed +
                        ' ' +
                        myDog.dogGender))
              ],
            ),
            new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(child: new Text('Kora: kb. ' + myDog.dogAge))
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I tried making this function async as well, and making it wait for the `fetchBasicDetails()` to finish, so the data is present when it would use it.

I even tried using `dynamic fetchBasicData(String URL) async {...}` but that didn't help either.
Using `Future<Dog>` instead of `dynamic` also causes errors.

How could I make the `buildBasicWidget` use the `fetchBasicData` result? Or should I just handle the widget building in the `fetchBasicData` as a simple workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `FutureBuilder` and add your `async` function in the `future` argument otherwise the `build` method gets called before the data are obtained.

Alternatively do your async request inside `initState`.

Comment: You should not call the async function in the `future` argument, as it will be restarted on every rebuild (e.g. firing a request per rebuild). Obtain the future during `initState`, `didUpdateConfig` or `didChangeDependencies` and pass it in your `build` method as the `future` argument. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html