# not able to update list after http call ( flutter)

Tags: http, dart, future, flutter

i'm new to flutter

i try to do an http call and then populate a list. The problem is that the http call works fine but the UI  doesn't refresh.
i think that the problem is that the framework create ui with the list before the http call is finish. Than when the http call is finished i'm unable to update the ui.

i've search but i didn't find anything.

**EDIT--FOUND SOLUTION IN Listview.Builder  [code here](https://github.com/francesco-taioli/flutter-card-demo)**

**http call**

```
 static Future<Map> getData() async {
    try{
    http.Response res = await http.get("http://...."); 
    Map data = JSON.decode(res.body);
    print(res.body);
    return data;
    }
    catch(exception){
      //todo
    }

  }
```

**main**

```
  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Widget> _items = new List<GithubCardItem>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("start download");
    _downloadData();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text(widget.title)),
        body: new ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => _items[index],
      itemExtent: 128.0,
      itemCount: _items.length,
    ),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          child: new Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: (){
            _downloadData();
          },
        )
    );
  }




 GithubCard _extractDataFromJson(Map githubCard){
     GithubCard card = new GithubCard(githubCard["name"], githubCard["avatar_url"], githubCard["description"], githubCard["stargazers_count"], githubCard["open_issued_count"]);
     return card;
}

  void _downloadData(){
    MyHttpCall.getData().then((jsonData) {
      //check if i have card to display
      if(jsonData["items"] != null){
        for(var githubCard in jsonData["items"]){
          setState(() {
            GithubCard card = _extractDataFromJson(githubCard);
            this._items.add(new GithubCardItem(card));
          });
          print("adding elements");
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

the GithubCardItem is a simple stateless widget that return a text.

Comment: Urelated to the problem but `return JSON.decode(exception);` doesn't make sense. The exception is not JSON.

Comment: yes, i will fix it

Comment: You should use a ’FutureBuilder` to get your view updated when the data  arrives from the server. There was a question about that yesterday or the day before yesterday.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550910/dart-flutter-building-widget-from-data-obtained-using-async-method-updated/49554789#49554789

Comment: i update the code. i do the http call inside the initState() but it doesn't work

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer in my code in same activity trying to call initstate api to refresh list data from alert success override method but its not reloading list data. any solution ?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer getting this error - Failed assertion: line 1312 pos 12: 'context != null': is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to use ListView as well as get data from network 
 here is the sample code for your problem

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List list = new List();
  void fetchData() {
    getData().then((res) {
      setState(() {
        list.addAll(res);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: ((BuildContext _context, int position) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text( list[position]['login'].toString()),
              subtitle: new Text(list[position]['url']),
              leading: new Image.network(list[position]['avatar_url']),
            );   
          }),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: fetchData,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<List> getData() async {
    var url = "https://api.github.com/users";
    List data = new List();
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    var response = await request.close();
    if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK) {
      var jsonString = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
      data = json.decode(jsonString);
      return data;      
    }else{
      return data;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i view your answer, i change the code but it doesn't work. I update the question

Comment: @TaioliFrancesco  try ListView.Builder as shown in mycode  above

Comment: i found the problem, now i update the post. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {----------- }

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {-----------}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List data;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("https://api.github.com/users"),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    this.setState(() {
      data = json.decode(response.body);
    });
    return "Success!";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Listviews"),
      ),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
          return new ListTile(
            title: new Text(data[position]['login'].toString()),
            subtitle: new Text(data[position]['url']),
            leading: new Image.network(data[position]['avatar_url']),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Made bit more simple and it's working. Check the sample [here](https://github.com/Rissmon/FlutterHttpRequest)